# Is it possible in boost.asio to bind to a specific NIC with link local address?

Tags: interface, bind, boost-asio, ipv6, link-local

as the asio documentation does not really live up to its name I have to ask this question. Help me Stackoverflow, you are my only hope ;)

We are talking in IPv6 here. I would like to tell asio to use a specific interface, like eth0, but without a global ip address, since I have only link local ones.
I would like to have something simliar to ping6 -I .
Is this possible with asio or do I have to use Berkeley Sockets for this?

Thank you in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

append the interface name after the IP address with a `%` delimiter

```
fe80::15c3:6bea:aaac:a016%eth0
```

taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5748034/283302).