# Strange symbols in IPv6 address in Java

Tags: java, network-programming, ipv6

When I call method `NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()`, i get the following string:

```
"fe80:0:0:0:f06c:31b8:cd17:5a44%5"
```

I wonder what `%5` means here? Is it possible to het IPv6 address without this `%5`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746082/ipv6-link-local-address-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's explained here:

[Inet6Adress - Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html#format)

> The general format for specifying the *scope_id* is the following:
>
> ```
> *IPv6-address%scope_id*
> ```
>
> The IPv6-address is a literal IPv6 address as described above. The
>   *scope_id* refers to an interface on the local system, and it can be
>   specified in two ways.
>
> 1. *As a numeric identifier.* This must be a positive integer that identifies the particular interface and scope as understood by the
>      system. Usually, the numeric values can be determined through
>      administration tools on the system. Each interface may have multiple
>      values, one for each scope. If the scope is unspecified, then the
>      default value used is zero.
> 2. *As a string.* This must be the exact string that is returned by [NetworkInterface.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getName()) for the particular interface in question.
>      When an Inet6Address is created in this way, the numeric scope-id is
>      determined at the time the object is created by querying the relevant
>      NetworkInterface.
>
> Note also, that the numeric *scope_id* can be retrieved from
>   Inet6Address instances returned from the NetworkInterface class. This
>   can be used to find out the current scope ids configured on the
>   system.

Answer (score 2):

The 5 is the zone index. The % is used to separate it.

A Windows machine would have one such as %1.

A Unix machine would have one such as %eth0. Using the interface name as the zone index.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation please?

Comment: Is this index important or I can trim it?

Comment: I'm afraid the zone index is actually an IPv4 thing (it's called differently in IPv6

Answer (score 0):

The % sign denotes the Ipv6 zone or scope id.

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will validate all standard representations of IPv6.  You can extract the zone as shown.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Code example:

```
        try {
            IPAddressString str = new IPAddressString("fe80:0:0:0:f06c:31b8:cd17:5a44%5");
            IPAddress addr = str.toAddress();
            if(addr.isIPv6() || addr.isIPv6Convertible()) {
                IPv6Address ipv6Addr = addr.toIPv6();
                String zone = ipv6Addr.getZone();
                IPv6Address noZoneAddr = new IPv6Address(ipv6Addr.getSection());
                System.out.println("zone is " + zone + " for address " + noZoneAddr);
            }
            //use address
        } catch(AddressStringException e) {
            //e.getMessage has validation error
        }
```

Output:

```
        zone is 5 for address fe80:0:0:0:f06c:31b8:cd17:5a44
```