# Inserting IPv6 into database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ipv6

my ip field in the mysql database is `VARBINARY(16)`

```
  // Insert into website table
    $ip = inet_pton('::1'); // Local ip
    $data_rec = array(
            'ip_address' => $ip,
            );  
    $this->db->insert('visitors', $data_rec);
```

The ip doesn't get inserted. It's a blank field. Why is that?

Comment: We have no idea how your `insert()` function works. Does it really accept an array?

Comment: Are IPv6 not upwards of 20 characters and even longer?

Comment: @Micheal Berkowski, seems like he is using the standard codeigniter insert function, so they should accept arrays.

Comment: @Jeemusu I didn't see the codeigniter tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inet_pton()` returns unprintable characters.
Did you try to read it from the database and do `echo inet_topn()`?

Given that I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `ip` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And using this simple script (all checks intentionally omitted for simplicity)

```
<?php
$in6_addr = inet_pton('::1');

$db = new mysqli('localhost', '******', '******', 'test');

$qry = "INSERT INTO ip (ip) VALUES('$in6_addr')";
$db->query($qry));

$qry = "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE id=1";
$result = $db->query($qry);
if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo inet_ntop($row['ip']);
}    
?>
```

you get the output

```
::1
```

But you can't see the value in phpAdmin or Sequel Pro

Comment: I am actually using Sequal Pro.. That really sucks if you can't see it.. What's the reason for that? Is there a way for me to see it or store it in another way then? I need to be able to see it in sequel pro.

Comment: Yes I actually did get ::1 output.. It sucks I can't see it in sequal pro though.. Is there some kind of fix for that

Comment: Well, the reason might be to store it in a compact form. That's exactly what `inet_pton()` does for you. How you would store it depends on what you would do with it other than looking at it in SequelPro or other IDE. Other options are: 2XBIGINTs, VARCHAR(39) or VARCHAR(45) depends on whether you need to support IPv4 tunneling. You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address?lq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database) to make right decision

Comment: I think I'll use VARCHAR(50). Thanks