# ".." (double dots) in otherwise valid IP4 addreses, e.g. 183.60..244.37

Tags: ip

My production server recently got a slew of access probes (to try and find a point to break in, to URI's like to /admin.php, /administrator, /wp-login.php, etc.), and I noticed that some of the REMOTE_ADDR's reported by Apache (IP4's) had two dots where there should be one.

What's up with this?  Is this some way for servers to hide?

For one, it means that I need to log these to a wider field than expected.  Expected would be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or 15 characters, but this might make it 16 or even 19.

[Edit: or better yet 50, see [this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address)

Comment: @Shane Madden: from php's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].  Is this what you were asking?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is happening in some code somewhere in your application (etc) that is doing formatting.

IP addresses are actually an array of 4 unsigned bytes.  They are conventionally represented character-wise (for human consumption) in "ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd" form, but that is not the fundamental representation.  The fundamental representation does not have dots in it at all.

It therefore follows that the extra dots you are seeing are some problem with either the way the IP addresses are converted to strings, or the resulting strings are incorporated into messages, or those messages are handled and ultimately displayed.  The extra dots do not "mean" anything ... except ... possibly ... to say that some characters have been left out.

Without more information, we can't tell you where those dots come from, or how to stop them.

---

> What's up with this? Is this some way for servers to hide?

Nope.

At the point that your systems first see those IP addresses, they are in 4-byte form, just like other IP addresses.  The dots are not a new way to hide.  Rather they are just a result of a local problem in the way things are being logged.

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at the evidence in your "half answer", one possibility is that you have some progress monitoring or debugging code somewhere that occasionally outputs a "dot" into the output stream.  It looks like it would be on a different thread ...

> So far my hosting company says only that I can clean up these values.

They are right.  But you probably want to find where your application is injecting the garbage and fix that ... rather than massaging the log files.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with that variable in your code?  I expect it's being translated or parsed in some way that's adding the extra period.

It's extremely unlikely that Apache would report it that way, as that would be invalid as an IPv4 address.

Compare your output with the web server's access logs, which will have recorded the remote IP as Apache saw it.

Comment: Interesting thought.  I'm looking at the actual logs right now and so far I only see 183.60.244.37.  However, my error reports are emailed and logged show both: 183.60.244.37 and sometimes 183.60..244.37, i.e. both ways. To answer your Q: My code puts this in a MySQL query using essentially: $query = "INSERT INTO log (IP) VALUES ('{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}');"; and then is used by code I've run for years without problems to call MySQL to execute it.  I'm guessing the Apache logger might clean it up so the log would be correct.  I'll go ask at Apache next.

Comment: From PHP documentation it appears that $_SERVER array is coming to PHP directly from the HTTP request headers, I'm guessing before Apache cleans them up.

Comment: @Elipticalview That's not entirely true, as the remote address is from the TCP connection, not the HTTP headers.  There's no cleanup that needs to happen with something that's straight from the system, and the web server would completely fall over and fail to serve the request if the system somehow claimed that the connection was from an IPv4 address with a `..`.

Comment: Humm?  Assuming that this http request is over TCP/IP and not from a tunnel or other HTTP transport protocol, e.g. HTTPU, or others I may not be aware of.  I will keep you posted as I find info on this.  Thanks for your help so far.  There has to be a reason for it.

Comment: @Elipticalview Well, I don't think it's likely that it's running on a different protocol like HTTPU since that's not really implemented in the real world or supported by Apache - but even so, UDP over IPv4 is still IPv4.  The much simpler explanation is the string getting mangled somewhere, either when being communicated from Apache to PHP or from PHP to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

**Half of the answer** is that php's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is untrusted because *<del>it comes directly from the http request as provided by the server to php</del>* it can apparently and from [other reports](http://rewindlife.com/2004/04/20/remote_addr-and-remote_host-not-safe-for-use-in-security/) be spoofed.

EDIT2: I have more recently found two more bad variables from $_SERVER with double dots, as follows:

```
  SERVER_ADDR         REMOTE_ADDR      REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT
184..154.227.128    183.60.244.30       1391788916.198
184.154..227.128    183.60.244.37       1391788913.537
184.154..227.128    183.60.244.37       1391788914.368
184.154..227.128    184.154.227.128     1391086482.1889

184.154.227.128     183..60.244.30      1391788914.1494
184.154.227.128     183..60.244.37      1391788913.0523

184.154.227.128     183.60..244.37      1391788911.5938
184.154.227.128     183.60..244.37      1391788914.3977

184.154.227.128     183.60.244.37       1391788911..9855
```

So far my hosting company says only that I can clean up these values.  That is easy, but cleaning up garbage is still garbage.  If dots can and are being added, then the numbers can and possibly are be changed too I think.  Humm?

See: [this comment from the php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#89567).

> Now that leaves the question where to find a trusted IP from the accessing client?  Apache has it I'm guessing from the incoming http packet exchange with the client.  (I'll ask this Q: in StackOverflow).