# What length can a network interface name have?

Tags: linux, database, windows, oracle, networking

I need to adjust some database tables in order to accommodate 50+ character long network interface names.
I wonder if there is a standard on how long an interface name can be, so I can map it correctly.

Comment: If you look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it seems like an adapter name could have a max length of 256 characters.

Comment: It seams 16 chars is correct of some flavors of Linux (tested on Centos 5), but not sure for the rest. I need to support both win/unix.

Comment: In that case I would go for 256 characters which seems to support both linux and windows.

Answer (score 45):

As far as the Linux-specific part of this, in recent kernel versions this is defined by [IFNAMSIZ](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/include/uapi/linux/if.h#L33) to be 16 bytes, so 15 user-visible bytes (assuming it includes a trailing null).  `IFNAMSIZ` is used in defining struct net_device's name field [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1826).

In order to test empirically, you can use the following to see that 16 bytes fails and 15 bytes works:

```
# CLEAN SLATE
root# ip link ls dev 123456789012345
Device "123456789012345" does not exist.
root# ip link ls dev 1234567890123456
Device "1234567890123456" does not exist.

# FAIL
root# ip link add dev 1234567890123456 type dummy
Error: argument "1234567890123456" is wrong: "name" too long
root# ip link ls dev 1234567890123456
Device "1234567890123456" does not exist.

# PASS
root# ip link add dev 123456789012345 type dummy
root# ip link ls dev 123456789012345
40: 123456789012345: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether ... brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# CLEAN UP
root# ip link del dev 123456789012345
```

(Assuming you have `ip` from the iproute2 package installed, as is likely on any Linux distribution from within the last decade or so.)

Comment: See also: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=704072
(Linux DHCP client has problems if device name has 14 or more characters and the `ip` command fails if device name has 16 or more characters.)

Answer (score 9):

Also, if you want to use the interface with DHCP, the name must have length  < 14, due to this issue:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=858580

Comment: That has allegedly been fixed in 2015, in version `4.3.2-1`, at least according to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=704072.