# What can be the max length of a docker-compose network name?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

In our jenkins2 pipeline we use docker-compose for some of our tests and our docker-compose file gets its network name from a combination of the branch name (git) and its build number.

Jenkins file fragment:

```
def version = "$BRANCH_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER"
def networkName = "network-$version"
sh "NETWORK_NAME=$networkName docker-compose up -d"
```

docker-compose.yml fragment:

```
version: '3.5'
networks:
  default:
    name: ${NETWORK_NAME}
    driver: bridge
```

It looks like when we have a short branch name everything goes fine and when we have a long branch name it fails.

How long can the network name be in docker-compose? I can't seem to find it in the documentation. 
Is there a better solution to get unique network names than going for the branch name?

I've tried this but it seems totally overkill somehow:

```
echo $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) | md5 | cut -f1 -d" "
```

will give md5 result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after not having had an answer after a few days I did some empirical testing of my own and found out that it is different for different OS's. I wanted to write my answer down for others with the same problem.

Here is what I found:

- docker on a mac mac can have very long network names and can even have `/` chars in it
- some linux distributions can have 16 chars (e.g. CentOs) and others 15 (e.g. Ubuntu).
- couldn't test on Windows as I have none available

So if you want to be save and have your docker-compose.yml work on different environments you should stick to a network name with a max length of **15** chars.

Also used this answer: [What length can a network interface name have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932172/what-length-can-a-network-interface-name-have)