# IP address is stored as 0 in SQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I am locally designing a website and I am testing a function within PHP that captures and stored the ip address of the client however I am simply getting a value of 0.
The code is:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
 } else {
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

The ip is then added to the mysql and stored as an integer using the code:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, email, salt, passhash, regdate, last_login_date,      regip, last_login_ip) VALUES ( NULL, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), ?, ?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);


    //i Interger
    //d Doubles         
    //s Everything Else


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssii", $email, $salt, $passhash, $ip, $ip);
```

Would the reason that the value is only 0 because I am running the website locally, or am I missing a step?

Thanks :)

Comment: What format is your ip address field in your db?

Comment: It is an unsigned integer

Comment: You might consider storing IPs as strings to enable future compatibility with IPv6 addresses. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address) for more info about storing IPv6 addresses.

Comment: php info states: RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 Is this 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't store your ip address in an unsigned integer field. Store it in an varchar format and it should fix your problem. Integer is expecting a normal number, not something with multiple `.` in it.

Comment: I read in a tutorial: All IP addresses should be stored in integer form. So instead of, say, "194.247.44.146", you would be storing 194*256^3 + 247*256^2 + 44 * 256^1 + 146, which is 3270978706. PHP has native functions that convert between human-readable-IPs and integer IPs, don't worry :) They're ip2long() and long2ip.  As it saves space.  The highest possible IP address is 255.255.255.255. Convert that and you get 4294967295, which is the maximum value for an unsigned int. Hence, ip fields are unsigned ints.

Comment: @dominicansell I see, usually when people indicate there storing IP addresses, it means there just storing it in the original format. I didn't realize you are altering it before storing. You should probably update the question with that information.

Comment: @dominicansell What database are you using? Also, is the value of `$ip` 0 before attempting to store in the db?

Comment: I am using SQL, I don't mind how I store the IP, just as long as the IP is stored in the database :) I don't set a original value to ip as I have set the column to be NULL to begin with. I have altered the columns to be varchar(45) and I am am attempting to input the ip as a string but I get the result ::1 in the table.

Comment: @dominicansell `::1` is the [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) address for IPv6. It's the equivalent of `127.0.0.1` in IPv4. Both formats are valid IP addresses. Note: `ip2long` and `long2ip` both won't work with IPv6 addresses as they expect them in IPv4 format.

Comment: So my code is working properly and when I launch the website online I will get actual IP adresses?