# cant get correct ip address into the database

Tags: php, sql, pdo, ip

I have the below simple code for inserting some failed login values in my database, but I have some problems:

1- The ip address is being saved in the database as zero no success whatever I do (going crazy on this).
2- I used current time stamp to get the date and time in a simple query, now that I use prepared statements it doesnt work with it, I am forced to use date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); which gives out the wrong time.

My code is:

```
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['Name'];
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $attempted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $query = "INSERT INTO failed_logins (username, ip_address, attempted) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"; 
    $failed = $conn->prepare($query);
    $failed->bindParam(1, $username);
    $failed->bindParam(2, $ip_address);
    $failed->bindParam(3, $attempted);
    $failed->execute();
?>
```

My ip_address row in the database is int(11) and it is unsigned.

Any suggestions would help thanks

**UPDATE:**

**I did the below but still no luck:**

I changed:

```
 $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

to this:

```
 $ip_address = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: `ip_address row in the database is int(11)` yeah thats wrong, you need to store it as a `VARCHAR(39)`

Comment: just a typo, fixed it, please remove the down vote

Comment: the part that makes it wrong is that it should be a varchar field.  ip addresses contain periods.

Comment: @Serjio An ip address has multiple dots in it. It's not an int value.

Comment: @cmorrissey, changed to VARCHAR(39), what should I set the attribute unsigned to?

Comment: what database management system are you using? mysql, ms sql server, etc.?

Comment: @cmorrissey The max length of an ipv6 address is 45 chars, not 39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am forced to use date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); which gives out the wrong
>   time.

Have you tried setting the `date_default_timezone_set`, i.e.:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

---

You cannot use an `int` to store a var containing **dots** ans **colons**.
Change the DB `ip_address` row from

```
int(11)
```

to

```
varchar(15); //ipv4
```

#### #

```
ALTER TABLE `sometable`
MODIFY COLUMN `ip_address` varchar(15);
```

Or

```
varchar(45); //ipv6
```

#### #

```
ALTER TABLE `sometable`
MODIFY COLUMN `ip_address` varchar(45);
```

if you want to store `ipv6` addresses

---

References:

[Maximum length of the textual representation of an IPv6 address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address)

Comment: my int is unsigned, and when I change to varchar database gives error, what should I change the attribute to?

Comment: You cannot use an `int` to store a variable containing dots ans colons

Comment: @ Pedro Lobito, ok I got that part well, now What should the attribute be for the varhcar here?

Comment: @Serjio I'm not following you. Which attribute ?

Comment: @Pedro Lobito, I mean the attributes part in the database for the ip_address row, when the type was int(11) the attribute was unsigned, but now that I changed to varchar it does not accept unsigned anymore, so what should the attribute be instead of unsigned?

Comment: You don't need to assign anything. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @PedroLobito, I got the date fixed, thanks man, I will up vote your answer for that, and I'll work in the ip now

Comment: You're very welcome @Serjio. Your code will work as soon as you change the fields on the db. You may want to use a mysql editor with gui, here's a few options for windows http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/manage-mysql-from-windows-with-these-five-apps/ .GL

Comment: OK I will work on it, if works I will accept it as answer, thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

Also maybe to get IP(ish):

```
(string)$ip_address = getRealIpAddr();

function getRealIpAddr() {
    (string)$ip='';
    if (array_key_exists('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', $_SERVER) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {   //check ip from share internet
      $ip .= filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    } elseif (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {   //to check ip is pass from proxy
      $ip .= filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    } else {
      $ip .= filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR');
    }
    return $ip;
}
```