# Why is INET6_ADDRSTRLEN defined as 46 in C?

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

The following program and its output shows that `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` is defined as `16` and `INET6_ADDRSTRLEN` is defined as `46`.

Here is the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("%d\n", INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output.

```
16
46
```

I can understand why `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` needs to be `16`. The largest possible string representation of an IPv4 address consumes 15 bytes, e.g. `"255.255.255.255"`. Therefore 16 bytes are required to store such an IP address with its terminating null character.

But why does `INET6_ADDRSTRLEN` need to be `46`? The largest possible string representation of an IPv6 address consumes only 39 bytes (according to my knowledge), e.g. `"ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff"`. Therefore only 40 bytes are required to store such an IP address with its terminating null character.

Is there a string representation of an IPv6 address that can consume 46 bytes?

Comment: Related: [Maximum length of the textual representation of an IPv6 address?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/166132/1068283)

Comment: FYI: For Windows programming, the values are #defined differently when you #include <winsock2.h>: in wsipdef.h, INET_ADDRSTRLEN is **22** and INET6_ADDRSTRLEN is **65**.
This accommodates for optional brackets around the IPv6 address with scope ID, a colon and a port number. For example: `[ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:255.255.255.255%2147483648]:65535` is 64 characters long and requires a 65 character buffer.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> Why is INET6_ADDRSTRLEN defined as 46 in C?

Because [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) defines it to be 46:

> INET6_ADDRSTRLEN
>   46. Length of the string form for IPv6.

While you are right that longtest IPv6 address takes 39 bytes, with IPv4 tunneling, the longest form can be 45 bytes:

```
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:255.255.255.255
```

And the 46th byte is for the terminating nul byte (in C a string). This explains how it came to be 46.

Answer (score 10):

It's probably for the IPv4-mapped form of addresses of the form:

```
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:255.255.255.255
```

Read more:

[Wireshark-dev mailing list](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201105/msg00061.html)

[RFC 4291 section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2)